# visual studio generated msi vs gpo: This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe

Tags: windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin, gpo, oneclick

I have outlook vsto addin with oneclick installer (vsto manifests etc) that is bundled with MSI. This is done to be able to install it with Group Policy (as I learned oneclick cannot be really deployed with GPO, it needs MSI).

This msi works fine if I run it from limited account (UAC prompts) or admin account.
Problem is that if it is deployed via GPO it shows:

> "This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe (...)"

I looked to stackoverflow and found that it could be run with /qb switch - but it doesn't work :(.

Somewhere in internet I found this is related to this: ERRCA_UIANDADVERTISED 
http://board.issociate.de/thread/401848/Advertised-application-will-not-be-installed.html

http://www.creativedocs.net/blog/index.php?serendipity%5Baction%5D=search&serendipity%5BsearchTerm%5D=versionmax

but to be honest I don't understand why visual studio almost defaul msi is not really deployable with GPO.
What exactly should I fix in my MSI in visual studio to make it working?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe try to right click the MSI, then go "**Properties**" and check towards the bottom of the property window if it says "*This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer*". If so, click the "**Unblock**" button and then "**OK**". Or tick the "**Remove blocking**" check box and press **OK**.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a per-user software using GPO without any issues. Basically, you can do tests before using GPO by silently installing your packages:

```
msiexec /i productname.msi /quiet
```

The issue is in publishing the MSI to a system where the user may not be privileged, so dialog boxes cannot be offered because that allows a limited user to control an install running privileged because it was published and is being installed in admin mode.

See ["This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic."](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smondal/2009/10/13/this-advertised-application-will-not-be-installed-because-it-might-be-unsafe-contact-your-administrator-to-change-the-installation-user-interface-option-of-the-package-to-basic/) for more information.